# Component v-if statement with properties in Nuxt / Vue (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a component that I'd like to conditionally render based on a property:

```
<template>
<div class="logoContainer" v-if="showLogo">
  LOGO
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export default class extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: true})
  showLogo: boolean
}
</script>
```

This generates the error: `Property or method "showLogo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.`

What's the easiest way to set & reference my `showLogo` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `vue-property-decorator` but based on the documentation, you are missing a few things.

```
<template>
<div class="logoContainer" v-if="showLogo">
  LOGO
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export class MyComponent extends Vue {
@Prop({default: true})
showLogo: boolean
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  I was importing Vue and exporting the component but missing the key piece -- `@Component`.  Interestingly, it would run without errors, other than the recommendation to read the Declaring-Reactive-Properties docs.